# Installing rpy2 on Opensuse 13.2 x64

Tags: r, python-2.7, pip

Trying to install rpy2 on a new Linux installation. Have installed R, ipython, python-devel etc on the system. When executing sudo pip install rpy2 I get an error - "missing python.h". This file is available on my system but not found.
What can I do?

Comment: can you add the path to `python.h` to your question?

Comment: I'm out of town for a while will get back with the info when I'm back